# Creating a Stereoscopic video from a Movie Clip using Blender Compositor

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes

I am trying to use the blender compositor to perform this conversion process to create a SBS video for use on Google Cardboard.

In principle it works by manipulating each individual frame in a movie clip (1280x720 resolution). I basically sample two images from each frame with one image offset horizontally 26.9% to the right of the other. Both these samples together constitute one SBS frame in the VR movie file.

This is my current node setup within Blender. However, the second region of the SBS frame doesn't render correctly. How do I fix this? I also need to render straight to the video file in mp4 format.

[image: compositor node setup]

Answer (score 0):

Ok with a few modifications finally have the frames displaying correctly but cant find a way to output directly to the video file. The still images are not of high quality especially with HD cameras alot of screen tearing. MP4 work better.VLC media player does a much better job extracting stills but cant get this outputting every single frame.

[image]